# Grammatical term for a noun phrase which consists of an alternate descriptor of the object

Tags: grammar, punctuation, terminology

(EDIT: It's called a noun phrase, not a clause)

I'm wondering what the correct term for this type of clause is, and what the appropriate punctuation is. For example:

> "I have lost my red hat, the hat I got for Christmas."

Is a comma the correct punctuation mark here, and what is the term for phraselike the one after the comma?

Comment: (1) the comma is correct. (2) the construction is called an ***Appositive***; the two noun phrases _my red hat_ and _the hat I got for Christmas_ are said to be ***in apposition***. (3) these are noun phrases, not clauses. There **is** a relative clause -- _(that) I got for Christmas_ -- in the last part, but it modifies _hat_ and is part of the noun phrase. Clauses always have a predicate, and normally a verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I have lost my red hat, the hat I got for Christmas."

It is a well-formed sentence, including the punctuation. :)

The expression *"the hat I got for Christmas"* is a noun phrase (NP) and is known as an **appositive** NP. That NP is part of a supplementary type of apposition, and could be substituted for the whole supplementation: *"I have lost the hat I got for Christmas."*--which is entailed by your original example.

The expression *"the hat (that) I got for Christmas"* is a noun phrase (NP), which is headed by the noun "hat(i)", and which has as a modifier the relative clause "(that) I got __(i) for Christmas".

(EDITED: Yeah, I type slow.)

Comment: Thank you. Should I edit the title to correct my mistake in referring to the noun phrase as a clause?

Comment: @karl Sure, why not. :) -- (Remember to edit the body of the text too.)